# Track the week intervals from the month start date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I'm trying to find how many runners signed up for each 1 week period starting from 2021-01-01. I've got no problem with the query but i'm unable to do a mod (%) with the date to reach a 7 day figure mark to round up my query.

```
---My Schema
CREATE TABLE runners (
  "runner_id" INTEGER,
  "registration_date" DATE
);
INSERT INTO runners
  ("runner_id", "registration_date")
VALUES
  (1, '2021-01-01'),
  (2, '2021-01-03'),
  (3, '2021-01-08'),
  (4, '2021-01-15');


runner_id   registration_date
1   2021-01-01
2   2021-01-03
3   2021-01-08
4   2021-01-15
```

Desired O/P:

```
start_of_week   signups
2021-01-01    2
2021-01-08    1
2021-01-15    1
```

```
---My Query

WITH data1 AS (
  SELECT
    runner_id,
    registration_date,
    REGISTRATION_DATE - (DATEDIFF(DAY, REGISTRATION_DATE, '2021-01-01' ) % 7)  AS start_of_week
  FROM runners
)
select start_of_week, count(runner_id) as signup from data1 group by start_of_week;
```

Error

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

I also tried switching the date formats to mod with 7 but didn't work.

```
 registration_date - ((registration_date - '2021-01-01') % 7)
```

Error

> The data types date and varchar are incompatible in the subtract operator.

Comment: Using a Modulo (`%`) on a date doesn't make sense, it's not a number. What are you *actually* trying to achieve here?

Comment: Sounds like you just need to count and group by week number?

Comment: @Larnu I'm trying to find out how many runners signed up for each 1 week period? (i.e. week starts 2021-01-01)

Comment: I think you don't need modulo, you need to divide into 7 and add 1 to get the week number. Also you don't need to subtract it from registration_date, which is date and the week number is an integer, hence the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as per comments, try this:

```
 WITH data1 AS (
  SELECT
    runner_id,
    registration_date,
    (datediff(DAY,  '2021-01-01',REGISTRATION_DATE ) / 7) + 1 AS start_of_week
  FROM runners
)
select
  dateadd(week, start_of_week - 1, '2021-01-01'),
  count(runner_id) as signup
from data1
group by start_of_week;
```

dbfiddle

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=91a00cf6223f3c1367b6e8f014dccd6f

you can also cast it as date if you want to get rid of the time

```
select
  cast(dateadd(week, start_of_week - 1, '2021-01-01') as date),
  count(runner_id) as signup
from data1
group by start_of_week;
```

Comment: this one is giving me -1,0,1 as start_of_week were as i want the dates and their signups like in the description.

Comment: @Mitt I don't think that is the case, please check the fiddle, make sure the start date is first and registration date second in the datediff

Comment: what i'm looking for is '2021-01-01 - 1..ie (registration_date | no_of_sign_ups).

Comment: @Mitt Ok, that's a small change. I updated the answer

Comment: You should learn to use `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` avoids the need for nested derived tables, also `COUNT(someNonNullValue)` is the same as `COUNT(*)`

Comment: @Jayvee Thanks for the answer! I'm curious to know how you reached to this solution. How will you know that you need to add +1 and then reduce 1 from start_of_week? Is it from experience/practices or blessed brains :-)

Comment: @Mitt you're welcome!. I'd say it's experience of having worked with dates in SQL many times; not always is straight forward and these 'tricks' come in handy.

Comment: Thank you mate!! Happy 2022 to you and your loved ones :)